# WPF CollectionViewSource is not Updating the Filtered Data on UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, collectionviewsource

By following [this](https://grantwinney.com/using-a-textbox-and-collectionviewsource-to-filter-a-listview-in-wpf/) blog post, I'm trying to add search and filter functionality in WPF application. Its a file browser application, I'm reading all the files, folders from a drive and by using MVVM I'm binding its content with the UI (`Listbox`). However, when I used the `CollectionViewSource` to add another layer to filter the data, I cannot see the filtered data on UI.

Would appreciate if anyone can explain how I can see the filtered data in UI. Thank you.

**Code behind**

```
public DefaultControl()
{
    Instance = this;
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

// When the listbox is initialized
private void detailList_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = DirectoryStructure.
      GetDirectoryContent(DirectoryPath).
      Select(drive => new DirectoryItem(drive.FullPath, drive.Type)).ToList();

    Items = new ObservableCollection<DirectoryItemViewModel>(data);

    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items).Filter = Search;
}

private bool Search(object obj)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBx_Search.Text))
        return true;

    var item = (DirectoryItemViewModel)obj;

    bool found = (item.Name.Contains(txtBx_Search.Text));

    return found;
}

// Listen the text change event of Textbox
private void OnSearchTextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items).Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the XAML, it might help spot the problem?

Comment: The problem statement and provided code is not enough to reproduce the issue (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You should supplement at least relevant part of your _XAML_ code and elaborate on what exactly do you mean by "I cannot see the filtered data" - are all items are visible (filter is not applied), or no items are visible (filter is not applied as expected), or something else?